# Peerguardian Error "Could not use either kdesu(do) or gksu(do) to execute the command requested"

Tags: wireless, sudo, ip

I installed PeerGuardian (thanks to a lot of help) and I get an error massage saying:

> Could not use either kdesu(do) or gksu(do) to execute the command requested. You can set the path of the one you prefer in "Options - Settings - Sudo front-end"

I'm new to Linux and PeerGuardian, so I don’t know where or how to get to these "options".

I Would be grateful if I was also told which addresses I should blacklist to torrent, and which ones to not so I can keep my WiFI, hotmail etc.

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using? iirc `gksu` was removed from the default installation of 14.04 so you may need to install it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the terminal do:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then:

```
gksu-properties
```

in the window that opens change authentication mode to sudo.[image: gksu]

Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but do you know I should white list to make it so I can use wifi?